# Display BufferedReader in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, bufferedreader

I am having some huge html content in BufferedReader. I am using struts2. So I have converted the BufferedReader to string and displayed in JSP with property file. But it doesn't display anything. I am not sure this approach is correct. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

This is my code.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    String line;

        stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stringbuffer.append(line);
        }

        stringVariable= stringbuffer.toString();
```

I have added getter setter method for stringVariable. This is my jsp code

```
<s:property value="stringVariable" />
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the string in order to see if it is created correctly?

Comment: @IlGala Yes I have logged, it is working. But I don't know how to display that in jsp.

Comment: Does the real `stringVariable` have a first word of one letter, like sOverflow ?

Answer (score 1):

As you have html content, in the string you must use

```
 <s:property value="stringVariable" escapeHtml="false" />
```

The `s:property` escape html by default.